# Excel if statement with string comparison

Tags: excel

How do I give an if statement in excel when we want to compare with a string?

I tried something like this:

```
=IF(B2="mystring", 595, B2)
```

Here basically, I am trying to replace a particular string in all the cells of a column with the number 595.

Comment: your formula is correct, and should work. What did you get instead? is your problem ignoring case differences? or what?

Comment: I am getting an Err:522

Comment: that's a circular reference. That means that you cannot refer in a formula to the same cell the formula sits in. Yoy need to create a new column for the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err 522 means you have a **circular reference**. You cannot refer in a formula to the same cell the formula sits in.

Yoy need to create a new column for the formula.

So, if you want to change values in column B

- create a new colum C
- in C2 put your formula `=IF(B2="mystring",333,B2)` there
- copy your formula to all cells in column C
- select your new column C
- copy
- paste special | values into column B

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(EXACT(B2,"mystring")=true,592,B2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try IIF(b2="my string", 595,b2)

Comment: `IIF` is not a valid function, did you mean `IF()`

Comment: it gives me an Err:522

Comment: IIF has existed in Excel since version 1.5. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557186.aspx.  However, it does seem to be missing from the worksheet functions and have been replaced with a more traditional if statement.  However, in this case, regular expressions might be a better choice.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx